# Can't control Ubuntu UI - because of hidden layer

Tags: 20.04, display, gui

My Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly acting really weird. I'm able to login. I can open what ever app. I like - BUT then I can't navigate and use the mouse or keyboard inside the app? It is like a hidden window is on top - because an extra close button shows up in top left corner? I can ONLY click on this extra new (red) close button - and close the window again...

No matter how many times I restart or shutdown the server the issue persists? And the issue is the same no matter if I remote to the machine (via TeamViewer) or use it directly (with connected keyboard and monitor).

CTRL + Q, ALT + F4 or right mouse-click on the windows in the taskbar doesn't work as well (even though the right-click-menu shows up and I click on Quit).

Please check my picture and video I have captured of the issue:

Screenshot (picture): https://www.screencast.com/t/agDPwfKBn

Screenshot (video): https://www.screencast.com/t/nCHf7hWBQ

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what happened to Ubuntu default Gnome UI...I tried to reinstall it - but it didn't help anything...the weird issue described above persists.

*I solved the issue by installing and switching to: Ubuntu-Mate-Desktop.*